# Dynamic routing in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

How would you manage an url structure like the one below?

I am migrating a project to Nuxt3 and I would like to understand if I can avoid managing redirects.

`/fashion` blog category fashion

`/fashion/page-3` blog category fashion page 3

`/fashion/35/cool-article` blog post from blog category fashion with id 35 and alias "cool-article"

The main problem I am encountering is that blog categories are dynamic, but there are also other dynamic routes and I don't want a general "catch all" vue file that handles everything, and I would like also to avoid loading all possible routes.

Comment: Maybe with query params?  `/fashion?page=3`  the path is still just `/fashion` but the component loaded by the route would be in charge of determining the content based on the query part of the URL.

Comment: @yoduh I would do like this if I have to do a project from scratch, in this case my aim was to keep the existing url structures in order to avoid redirects when migrating the existing project tu Nuxt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the routes you've listed, I'd create following structure inside Nuxt's dedicated `/page` directory:

```
-| pages/
---| [category]/
------| [item]/
---------| [alias].vue
------| page-[page].vue
------| index.vue
```

1. `/pages/[category]/index.vue` would look like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <CategoryShow :category="category" :page="1" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const category = useRoute().params.category
</script>
```

This will trigger for `/fashion` route (page named "index" is always a default fallback if no other defined route matches). Inside Nuxt build-in `useRoute()` composable via its `params` array there is the current value of the dynamic parameter. Nuxt automatically fills this array based on parts of the route enclosed inside square brackets. The extracted value will be passed as a prop into dedicated `/components/Category/Show.vue` file. Here you would handle the displaying.

I assumed a default value for "page". But it is also possible to make the prop optional inside the component and just omit it here.

2. `/pages/[category]/page-[page].vue` will look quite the same, just it also handles the page:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <CategoryShow :category="category" :page="page" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const category = useRoute().params.category
const page = useRoute().params.page
</script>
```

This will consume  `/fashion/page-3` route. In that case the value of `category` will be `fashion` and value of `page` would be `3`.

3. `/pages/[category]/[item]/[alias].vue` would be:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <ArticleShow :item="item" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const item = useRoute().params.item
</script>
```

I believe you only need `item` part of the route to identify and display the desired article, but written like this it will catch all possible routes like `/fashion/35/cool-article`. Params `category` and `alias` will be available, if you need them for some reason.

This is how I would handle the given route examples. But since you mention "other dynamic routes", I am not sure, if it is the right approach. But I would generally try to fit all my content to match contents of `/page` directory, because like that Nuxt gives me powerful and quite complex routing out of the box with little-to-zero effort.

If you need more, there is also [`useRouter()` composbale](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-router), that wraps underying VueRouter and allows manual interaction with the routes.

Comment: Your approach is the one I used in the end, I just added some rules in the ```pages:extend``` hook in order to reuse the same ```.vue``` files for multiple cases